# Windows 10 recovering by itself and fails to boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, windows-update

During last week's windows 10 update, a computer in my house rebooted and started the "Reset your PC" process (as in reset to factory defaults) of the computer. The reset did not succeeded and the machine eventually stopped.

Since then, when we start the computer it starts the reset to and stops the same way.

It is important to note that because we had issue with the old one, the hard is brand new, and the windows is a fresh install from 2 weeks ago.

Does anyone have any idea ? You'd be my hero!

Comment: By "reset" do you mean Windows attempted to "Reset" your installation or something else?

Comment: Do you mean "Reset" or "Restart"? *Reset* is to return to an earlier state (e.g. before installation of an update), "Restart" is to shut down and reboot.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik By "reset" I mean returning to a "factory state" (in android terms)

Comment: Turns out I did not have some pieces of information. The reset worked fine (but still, shouldn't have happened), and the computer was not stopping but hibernating: The login screen was on an other monitor that was off, and we did not notice this thanks to Windows showing a black screen at the login stage on the non-main screens. So there is basically no issue. As to why windows decided to reset, or that the second monitor should be the main screen...